# Update array of objects using a key variable

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and I'm trying to update values in the array based on one of the object's keys.

I'm having difficulty storing my Key as a variable.

In this instance the object looks like so

[image]

If I'm to store my Object Key as a variable it fails and just adds the new element

```
    let keyDataField = 'AUDCASH';
    for (let i = this.CellRow + 1; i < this.cash2.length; i ++)
    {
      this.cash2[i].keyDataField = 0;
    };
```

If it's hardcoded it works

```
    for (let i = this.CellRow + 1; i < this.cash2.length; i++) {
      this.cash2[i].AUDCASH = 0;
    };
```

Any idea on how i can pass a variable please?

Comment: Just use [ ] to define the key . Replace this.cash2[i].keyDataField = 0;  with this.cash2[i][keyDataField] = 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it needs to be in `[]`

```
let keyDataField = 'AUDCASH';
for (let i = this.CellRow + 1; i < this.cash2.length; i ++)
{
  this.cash2[i][keyDataField] = 0;
};
```

see how when you are using the variable i, you can't just do cash2.i, same goes with any other variable you want to use as a key. What it is currently doing is looking for a key called `keyDataField` rather than what is in the `keyDataField` variable

Answer (score 0):

The first case doesn't work for you because in

```
let keyDataField = 'AUDCASH';
for (let i = this.CellRow + 1; i < this.cash2.length; i ++)
{
  this.cash2[i].keyDataField = 0;
};
```

you are trying to set the key `keyDataField` a value and the `dot` notation doesn't resolve the variable for you.

You should be using the brackets notation

```
this.cash2[i][keyDataField] = 0;
```